# LNK2005 error in debug mode only

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, ace

Usually I eventually manage to sort out these LNK2005 (symbol already defined in object) errors but this one has me beat. I have a VS2010 solution containing several projects among them a project outputting an executable. This executable depends on libraries contained within the same solution thus I have added them into the "References" list for the executable project so that they get linked in automatically.

Now what happens when I try to build my executable (Server.exe) is that everything builds successfully when the *release* configuration is selected, but if I switch over to *debug* I get the following LNK2005 error:

```
error LNK2005: "public: class ACE_SOCK_Stream & __thiscall ACE_Svc_Handler<class ACE_SOCK_Stream,class ACE_NULL_SYNCH>::peer(void)const " (?peer@?$ACE_Svc_Handler@VACE_SOCK_Stream@@VACE_NULL_SYNCH@@@@QBEAAVACE_SOCK_Stream@@XZ) already defined in Shell.obj     network.lib(network.dll)    Server (server\Server)
```

As can be seen in the error the projects use the [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) library.

I have had a look at `ACE_Svc_Handler<class ACE_SOCK_Stream,class ACE_NULL_SYNCH>` that is mentioned in the error and found out that one exported class in the `network.dll` inherits from it:

```
class DLL_API NetHandler : public ACE_Svc_Handler < ACE_SOCK_STREAM, ACE_NULL_SYNCH >
{
    ...
}
```

...and in the `Server.exe` there is also one class inheriting from it:

```
class Shell : public ACE_Svc_Handler < ACE_SOCK_STREAM, ACE_NULL_SYNCH >
{
    ...
}
```

The `peer()` method mentioned in the error is then used by both the `NetHandler` and `Shell` classes.

I am not sure if, and if so why, this would cause a LNK2005 error? What confuses me even more is that I only get the linker error in *debug* mode. I should also mention that the `NetHandler` class exported by `network.dll` is not used by the `Server.exe`, other projects that also depend on the `network.dll` do however.

Any ideas what could be causing this and how it can be solved? I am not sure where I should continue to investigate.

UPDATE: If I don't export the `NetHandler` class in my `network.dll` the linker error goes away, but I need to export that class.

UPDATE 2: I found this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/168958) in a different question about LNK2005 and although the link doesn't describe my scenario exactly I tried the proposed solution and I managed to get rid of the linker error if I place the following line before `class Shell...` in my `Server.exe` project:

```
extern template class __declspec(dllimport) ACE_Svc_Handler < ACE_SOCK_STREAM, ACE_NULL_SYNCH >;
```

So what does this line do exactly? Does it tell the Server project to not define `ACE_Svc_Handler < ACE_SOCK_STREAM, ACE_NULL_SYNCH >` itself but instead import it from one of the linked in libraries?

Comment: This is probably a mismatch between inline settings when you compile ACE and when you compile your application. Check the defines set as compile flags when you compile ACE, especially the ones with *INLINE* in their name. Make sure you set the same when you compile your application.

Comment: You could be right, I have had some problems using the debug version of the ACE lib that I built myself. I have defined `__ACE_INLINE__` both when I built the ACE library and my projects (release mode works without `__ACE_INLINE__`) because I remember getting several "unresolved external symbols" for ACE_OS::memset, ACE_OS::memmove and ACE_OS::gettimeofday to mention a few. I have ported this project from Linux and this is the first time I have come into contact with ACE so perhaps I am doing something wrong.

Comment: On Windows we have different inline settings for debug and release mode, something to check at your side

Comment: From what I can see in config-win32-common.h `__ACE_INLINE__` is defined by default for release mode but it is not in debug mode. That's why I added it myself among the preprocessor definitions of the ACE library project and my projects. By doing this I thought I would get the same behavior as in release mode. But the linker error refuses to go away.

Comment: Have you recompiled ACE after you have changed the ace/config.h file?

Comment: Yes I did, I also changed the vc11/12 solution that was included with ACE 6.3.0 in order to open it in vc10 but that should not affect how the library is built right? I have updated the original question with a change I made that makes the linker error go away, haven't tried to run the executable yet tough.